# Automotive Voltage Regulation for MCU

Tags: voltage-regulator, automotive

To supply 5V to a PIC in a 12-15V automotive environment, I have so far been using variants of 7805s, or the HV varieties of PIC. While they work, obviously they aren't really of sufficient protection for the environment. In particular reversed polarities, and battery 'jump starts' can cause problems of the destructive variety.

My circuits draw very little current (100mA is a typical maximum) and I solder through hole by hand, so I would avoid SMD

Can anybody recommend either a good way to protect a simple 7805 (or 78L05), or some alternatives to the 7805 that are more suitable for the environment? I have so far found a suggestion of LM2937, but this is relatively very expensive (some 10x more than a 7805)

As a side question, is there a good way to find automotive grade components? I usually use farnell's catalogue, but they don't seem to have 'automotive' in their parametric search so it is a matter of scouring datasheets, which is time consuming.

Comment: Generally, you can just use a car usb adaptor. Better than a linear regulator.

Comment: This is as part of circuits to be used as modifications to existing wiring etc, in the engine bay and other places as permanent fixtures.

Comment: What is your price point for the 7805 regulators? These days, the AMS1117-5.0 LDO sells for under 8 cents each. Though the low cost ones I use are surface mount components, the leads are quite big and well-spaced-out, so it isn't too hard to hand-solder, even onto a perfboard/veroboard. I too solder most of my prototypes by hand, so I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: @Jon well, for the engine bay or high heat, sure, you would need automotive grade parts, but for anywhere in the cab/trunk, a simple car usb adaptor can be gutted for the parts and permanently wired in just fine.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - I have been using 78L05 @ (UK price) £0.10 in bulk, with cheap ceramic caps either side. The cheapest LM2937 is around £1.00 in bulk, but requires fancypants tantalum caps (due to ESR requirement) on top @ 0.30ea. I'm happy to spend it if necessary, but if there is a cheaper option that will work as good, then I would do that. However, if that means half a dozen extra discretes it will not be such a saving (due to time spent soldering)

Comment: @Jon For such a situation, an auto-grade high-joule suppressor / choke + TVS, plus a fast clamp diode / zener as a shunt should do the trick - perhaps not ideal but functional. Also, while you are at it, you might as well switch to the much much cheaper AMS1117 LDO, since you don't have that much current to cope with. One of my designs did use an automotive rated MOV + (IIRC) common mode choke + clamp, but it would occasionally die, hence changed it to the buck + LDO.

Comment: Are you able to show me how that would go together? Would be very much appreciated...

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Also when you say 'not ideal' are there likely events that would lead to destruction? (malfunction would be no problem as these are 'just for fun' not safety items). I have another failure of understanding related to the ESR requirements of the LM2937 caps but I will ask a separate question on that for my learning rather than for this problem.

Comment: @Jon Not ideal = "regulator dies". I never really checked why, because going with a buck regulator was the simpler, lazier, and more importantly, quicker option - prototype needed to ship *now! Can't provide details but a web search will show you some answers.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Then maybe the best option is to go for the LM2937 and be done with it...if I can find out why they require ESR of <3ohm, but can't find caps less than 6ohm...which makes me assume I need several.....

Comment: @Jon A quick search on digikey.com for 10 to 20 uF through-hole film capacitors or tantalum capacitors, with ESR below 3 Ohms, gives me 2 pages of film cap results, and over 10 pages of results for tantalum capacitors. Also, my reading of the datasheet shows a requirement of 3 Ohms or lower ESR, not 30 Ohms, am I reading something wrong?

Comment: Typeface issue! Yes, 3 Ohm not 3ohm.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Hmm...maybe I'm searching wrong. Yes I am, please ignore my silliness. I was looking for 0.1 and 0.33uF due to confusion with the 7805

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - sorry to keep banging on! One very last question... I can find a tantalum cap (as recommended in the datasheet) Multicomp CB0J336M2CCB, 33uF 6.3V 3Ohm, which is considerably cheaper than any other (mostly 10V+) - as I am regulating to 5V is this acceptable as the output cap do you think? I'm always suspicious of an unusually cheap part...

Comment: @jon Extended discussions really need to go onto [EE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), not comments.

Answer (score 6):

An automotive-rated voltage regulator will necessarily be priced significantly higher than the super-cheap 7805, due to the latter's massive sales volume and lack of high voltage spike protection, if nothing else.

Setting aside the input reversal case, which is easily addressed with a high current diode at the input, the options are:

- A Transient Voltage Suppressor (TVS) and / or a clamping diode shunt at the input
- A combination of common mode auto-rated choke coil and clamping diodes at input
- A DC-DC buck regulator designed to withstand the likely extreme case voltages

The LM2937 fits that third category, but there are less expensive options available.

For instance, there has been excellent personal experience with pre-built DC-DC regulator modules based on the [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) buck regulator, available on eBay.com for [less than $2](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Adjustable-Converter-Power-Module-Regulator-LM2596-hv2n-/300896872803?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item460ed9e963) including free international shipping:

[image: LM2596 module]

This module is rated for up to 35 Volts input, and copes well with transients on the input supply, as well as significant temperature swings. The output is adjustable, so one can set it to 5 Volts and forgets about it, for all general purposes.

For a supply-noise-sensitive design, a two step design is my preference: The above type of buck regulator set to say 6.5-7 Volts output, feeding into a linear regulator such as 7805 or better yet, one of its newer low drop-out counterparts such as the [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf), probably cheaper than a 7805 at [just over **7 cents** apiece](http://www.ebay.com/itm/50pcs-AMS1117-5-0-LM1117-5-0-AMS1117-LM1117-5-0V-1A-Voltage-Regulator-SOT-223-/281105719318?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item417334e016) for 50 units.

The **added advantage** of the buck regulator is that it generates less heat than a linear regulator, for any significant current, by dint of the different mechanisms of voltage regulator between the two technologies. Efficiency of 65 to 80% is common with a buck regulator, much less so with a linear regulator that needs to dump `7 Volts x Load_Current` Watts through heat emission.